# If I want to specialise just one method in a template, how do I do it?

Tags: c++, templates

Say I have a templated class like

```
template <typename T> struct Node
{
    // general method split
    void split()
    {
        // ... actual code here (not empty)
    }
};
```

Need to specialise this in the Triangle class case.. something like

```
template <>
struct Node <Triangle*>
{
    // specialise the split method
    void split() {}
} ;
```

but I *don't* want to rewrite the entire template over again!  The only thing that needs to change is the `split()` method, nothing more.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can provide a specialization for only that function outside the class declaration.

```
template <typename T> struct Node
{
    // general method split
    void split()
    {
        // implementation here or somewhere else in header
    }
};
```

// prototype of function declared in cpp
    void splitIntNode( Node & node );

```
template <>
void Node<int>::split()
{
     splitIntNode( this ); // which can be implemented
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   Node <char> x;
   x.split(); //will call original method
   Node <int> k;
   k.split(); //will call the method for the int version
}
```

If `splitIntNode` needs access to private members, you can just pass those members into the function rather than the whole Node.

Comment: Really? I didn't think this was possible.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit code sample added, I couldn't remember the exact syntax and wanted to test it first.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit : I didn't either ... learned something new +1 :-)

Comment: BTW, does this only work for full specializations, or can it work for partial specializations as well?

Comment: @Jason beats me... one way to find out :). Well, actually two, but checking the standard isn't as fun as trying it out.

Comment: Very nice.  I also tried declaring `template <Triangle*> void split() { }` inside `struct Node` and it worked, but this way is cleaner

Comment: Looks like [my attempts](http://ideone.com/IGvO7) at partial specialization aren't working whereas the [fully-specialized](http://ideone.com/q0AWh) version does ... :(

Comment: Wait, my previous comment _doesn't_ work, it only compiles (`template <Triangle*> void split() { }`).  [See next question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9331036/what-is-this-template-specialization-code-doing-and-why-does-it-compile-but-n)

Comment: @bobobobo also an interesting question :)

Comment: And if you want to hide the implementation of the specialised function, i.e. you want to put it in a compilation unit, the best way is to just create "stubs" of the implementation you want to call and put that in the compilation unit.

Answer (score 9):

Your case is a fortunate example because you are fully-specializing the template.  In other words there is only one template argument, and for the function you wish to specialize, you are providing a fully-specialized instantiation of that function definition. Unfortunately for *partial* class template specialization, it is a requirement that you re-implement the class.

For example, this works:

```
template<typename T, typename U>
struct Node
{
    void function() { cout << "Non-specialized version" << endl; }
};

template<>
void Node<int, char>::function() { cout << "Specialized version" << endl; }
```

The partially specialized version though will not work:

```
template<typename T, typename U>
struct Node
{
    void function() { cout << "Non-specialized version" << endl; }
};

template<typename U>
void Node<int, U>::function() { cout << "Specialized version" << endl; }
```

What you may want to-do if you find yourself in the second scenario, in order to avoid the needless duplication of code, is pack all the common elements into a common base-class, and then place all the elements that will be varying with the partial specialization in a derived class.  That way you do not need to reduplicate all the common code in the base-class, you would only need to re-write the definitions for the specialized derived class.

Answer (score 6):

Just define some

```
template<>
void Node<Triangle*>::split()
{
}
```

after the primary template, but before the first time you ever instantiate it.

Answer (score 2):

Awkward method that I usually use: Declare a "basic" template implementation. Then declare your template implementation, the default implementation would just inherit the "basic" one. The customize would inherit the "basic", plus override specific methods. Like this:

```
template <typename T> struct NodeBase
{
    // methods
};

template <typename T> struct Node
    :public NodeBase<T>
{
    // nothing is changed
};

template <> struct Node<SpecificType>
    :public NodeBase<SpecificType>
{
    // re-define methods you want
};
```

Note that the "method overriding" has nothing to do with virtual functions or etc. It's just a declaring a function with the same name and parameters as in the base - the compiler will automatically use it.

Comment: I've always done it this way, but I can see from the other answers that if it's just a class method, this isn't necessary ... you learn something new every day!