# Specialized function in non specialised Template class

Tags: c++, templates

Please refer to the below code
 [Specialized function in non specialized Template class](http://ideone.com/KiaWb)
Is it possible to write a specialized function foo, for non specialized template class MyClass [Line Number 7] ? If yes, then, what is the syntax for the same.
Regards,
Atul

Comment: Don't use macros for writing `template` line. It's difficult to understand. Moreover, what is your question ? Doesn't the code shown in the link, answers the same ?

Comment: Not clear on the question.  What is foo specializing?

Comment: @ iammilind :: The question I wanted to ask is, suppose i want to implement function foo for MyClass<bool> in a different way, and i don't want to use a specialised Template class (as what i have done in the code), then is it possible ? If yes, then how to achieve it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done if you create a full specialization of the class template.  Just refer to the answer in this question: [If I want to specialise just one method in a template, how do I do it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9330561/if-i-want-to-specialise-just-one-method-in-a-template-how-do-i-do-it/9330636#9330636)

Otherwise if you want to have a given function with the same signature have two different behaviors depending on the instantiated version of the class, and that instantiation is a *partial specialization* of the template class, you will have to make a separate specialization of the template class.

Keep in mind that if you want to avoid redundant code in this second case, you can always create a base template class that will have the functionality that will not change, and then create derived template classes that will contain the unique functionality necessary for each partial specialization.

Comment: Jason, However, this does not seem to work for template class with multiple typenames. Please refer the below code        http://ideone.com/fpikG

Comment: The one that doesn't work in your example is called a *partial specialization* of a class template, and is the condition I mentioned in my answer that won't work ... you'll have to create an entire definition for the partially specialized class.  If you'd like to know what syntax to use, just Google or search S.O. for "partial template specialization" ... you'll find tons of information.

Answer (score 2):

Look at my example below, I have tried answer your question (if I guessed right) in the simplest code possible by me:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template<typename T>
class Some
{
public:
    template<typename U> void foo(U val);
};

template<typename T>
template<typename U>
void Some<T>::foo(U val)
{
    cout << "Non specialized" << endl;
}

template<>
template<>
void Some<char>::foo(char val)
{
    cout << "Char specialized" << endl;
}

int main()
{
    Some<int> t1;
    t1.foo(5);

    Some<char> t2;
    t2.foo('c');

    return 0;
}
```

1. The important thing to note here is that "You cannot specialize your class and function   Independently" i.e you have to specialize both at the same time as done in the example.
2. Also, with this you lose the opportunity to specialize your class for that data type "char" in this case. (Need to confirm on this).

**UPDATE** :: Confirmed on point 2.

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to specialize MyClass< bool >::Foo, it would look like this:

```
template <>
void MyClass<bool>::Foo(bool A)
{
  // code goes here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking that,

(1) you want a function `Foo()` which doesn't take any argument and
    returns `void` inside `MyClass`

(2) This `Foo()` should be exclusive to the `MyClass` when the
    template type is `bool`, i.e. only for `MyClass<bool>`

then here is the way:

```
template<class Precision>
class MyClass {
  ...
public:
  ...
  void Foo ();  // don't implement here
};
...
template<>
void MyClass<bool>::Foo ()  // implementing only for 'MyClass<bool>'
{        // invoking for other 'MyClass<>' will result in compiler error
  ...
}
```